# Run script to setup environment in VSCode after connecting to container or before compling/debugging

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I am working on a docker containerized c++ project that has defined shell scripts to setup the environment (using "source") for compiling and debugging. They have a lot of environment variables and could change at anytime so it would be hard to move them all into the launch.json file (and tedious to keep up with) so I need to call them before compiling or debugging.

The scripts only need to run once so if there was a way to run them after connection to the container that would be the best solution, however I cannot find anything like that.

I have tried to use the "preLaunchTask" in the launcher to run a task before debugging but it seems that the task's shell is different from the debug shell.

Is there anyway to handle this?

For the moment I am using a task to generate a .env file

```
printenv > ${workspaceFolder}/.preenv && . ${workspaceFolder}/setupEnv && 
printenv > ${workspaceFolder}/.postenv && grep -vFf 
${workspaceFolder}/.preenv ${workspaceFolder}/.postenv > 
${workspaceFolder}/.env
```

Answer (score 0):

I have VSCode mount a directory as the container's homedir, and then put a `.bash_profile` file containing the necessary setups (or other suitable shell startup file) in that directory.

My `/path/to/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` includes:

```
    "mounts": [
        "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/.devcontainer/home,target=/home/username,type=bind,consistency=delegated"
    ],
    "remoteUser": "username",
    "userEnvProbe": "loginShell",  // Ensures .bash_profile fires
```

Then my `/path/to/.devcontainer/home/.bash_profile` contains the necessary invocations to set my environment.